# C# - Windows 2000 BalloonTip Events workaround

Tags: c#, windows-2000, balloon-tip

Ive been looking all over for a workaround for this but have found nothing besides "Just have them click the NotifyIcon".

Windows 2000 obviously does not support BalloonTip events but I need a way to detect when either the balloon tip is clicked or closed. So I was thinking if there was a way for my program to know if the balloonTip is currently displayed, then I can create a timer that checks if the balloonTip is no longer displayed. Maybe something like this:

```
timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!balloonTipDisplayed())
    {
        //balloon is closed, do somthing...
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Or maybe have a better workaround?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took what Chris said and ended up finding this great project:
[TaskbarNotifier](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx)

It works in 2000 and XP which is just what i need, and it even looks nicer than a balloonTip.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out there to resolve that AFAIK.  There is no event in the Windows 2000 UI which can be fired.  It's something I battled with for a while and ended up writing something to do it instead for just Windows 2000.  I used another Windows Form which was shown "always on top" in the bottom right hand corner of the screen to emulate it.  Not pretty but it worked :)